# How can I improve speed of DataTable group by Day method

Tags: c#, performance, linq, datatable

I have about 300K rows in a DataTable. The first column is "utcDT" which contains a DateTime with minutes.

I want to group the data by Date into a list of "ReportDailyData". My method is below but takes around 8 seconds to run. I need to make this significantly faster.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
public class ReportDailyData
{
    public DateTime UtcDT;
    public double Day_Pnl;
    public int TradeCount;
    public int Volume;

    public ReportDailyData(DateTime utcDT, double day_Pnl, int tradeCount, int volume)
    {
        UtcDT = utcDT;
        Day_Pnl = day_Pnl;
        TradeCount = tradeCount;
        Volume = volume;
    }

    public string AsString()
    {
        return UtcDT.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "," + Day_Pnl.ToString("F2") + "," + TradeCount + "," + Volume;
    }
}

public static DataTable Data;
public static DataSpecification DataSpec;

public void Go()
{
     //Fill Data and DataSpec elsewhere

     var dailylist = GetDailyData();
}

   public List<ReportDailyData> GetDailyData()
    {
        List<ReportDailyData> dailyDatas = new List<ReportDailyData>();
        DateTime currentDT = DataSpec.FromDT.Date;
        while (currentDT <= DataSpec.ToDT.Date)
        {
            var rowsForCurrentDT = Data.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("utcDT").Date == currentDT).ToList();
            if (rowsForCurrentDT.Any())
            {
                double day_Pnl = rowsForCurrentDT.Sum(x => x.Field<double>("Bar_Pnl"));
                var positions = rowsForCurrentDT.Select(x => x.Field<double>("Position")).ToList();
                var deltas = positions.Zip(positions.Skip(1), (current, next) => next - current);
                int tradeCount = deltas.Where(x => x != 0).Count();
                int volume = (int)deltas.Where(x => x != 0).Sum(x => Math.Abs(x));
                dailyDatas.Add(new ReportDailyData(currentDT, day_Pnl, tradeCount, volume));
            }
            else
            {
                dailyDatas.Add(new ReportDailyData(currentDT, 0, 0, 0));
            }

            currentDT = currentDT.AddDays(1);
        }

        return dailyDatas;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly - you want to perform grouping on some data collection, is that right?

If so - why not to use linq: GroupBy method?

A simple example is below:

```
    void Main()
    {
        var data = new List<MyData>();
        data.Add(new MyData() { UtcDT = DateTime.UtcNow, Volume = 1 });
        data.Add(new MyData() { UtcDT = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1), Volume = 1 });
        data.Add(new MyData() { UtcDT = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1), Volume = 4 });
        data.Add(new MyData() { UtcDT = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-2), Volume = 5 });
        var result = GroupReportDataAndFormat(data);
    }

    public Dictionary<DateTime, int> GroupReportDataAndFormat(List<MyData> data)
    {
        return data.GroupBy(t => t.UtcDT.Date).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Sum(s => s.Volume));
    }

    public class MyData
    {
        public DateTime UtcDT { get; set; }
        public int Volume { get; set; }
    }
```

Of course - for performance reasons, you probably should do grouping on database level (compose query to return your data, that is already grouped)

=== UPDATE =====

MainInMoon : I've updated solution to fit your case:

```
void Main()
{
    var data = new List<MyData>();

    data.Add(new MyData() { UtcDT = DateTime.UtcNow, DayPnl = 1, Positions = 3 });
    data.Add(new MyData() { UtcDT = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1), DayPnl = 1, Positions = 4 });
    data.Add(new MyData() { UtcDT = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1), DayPnl = 4, Positions = 5 });
    data.Add(new MyData() { UtcDT = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-2), DayPnl = 5, Positions = 6 });
    var result = GroupReportDataAndFormat(data);
}

public Dictionary<DateTime, GroupResult> GroupReportDataAndFormat(List<MyData> data)
{
    return data.GroupBy(t => t.UtcDT.Date).ToDictionary(
        k => k.Key, v => new GroupResult
        {
            DayPnlSum = v.Sum(s => s.DayPnl),
            Deltas = v.Select(t => t.Positions).Zip(v.Select(s => s.Positions).Skip(1), (current, next) => next - current)
        });
}

public class GroupResult
{
    public double DayPnlSum { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<double> Deltas { get; set; }
    public int TradeCount
    {
        get
        {
            return Deltas.Where(x => x != 0).Count();
        }
    }
    public int Volume
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)Deltas.Where(x => x != 0).Sum(x => Math.Abs(x));
        }
    }
}
public class MyData
{
    public DateTime UtcDT { get; set; }
    public int DayPnl { get; set; }
    public double Positions { get; set; }
}
```

Of course, you can change TradeCount and Volume properties to be calculated during grouping (not lazy loaded)

Comment: I have a more complicated Zip in my version. Hence, why I am not using Group By.

Comment: Wow! That is orders of magnitude faster. I don't understand why - but thank you

Comment: I suppose, that main reason for performance issue was this (in a loop):

Data.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("utcDT").Date == currentDT).ToList();

Also - watch out for "ReportDailyData.AsString()" method - as it creates many copies of strings. If it is also used in some loop - it can cause memory performance issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150632/discussion-between-maninmoon-and-piotr).

Answer (score 0):

I would advise: sort on the utcDT, then enumerate the result linearly and do the grouping and aggregation manually into a new data structure.  For every new utcDT value you encounter, create a new ReportDailyData instance, then start aggregating the values into it until utcDT has the same value.